# Sending data from React using Axios to Django - Post request is empty

Tags: reactjs, django, axios

I am trying to send data from React via axios to the Django.

Here is the code on the React Side:

```
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN";
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken";
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true

sendData = () => {
    let formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('picture', this.state.files.height, this.state.files.name)
    axios.post("/api/async_function/", formData, {
        headers: { 'accept': 'application/json','content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },}).then(resp => { console.log(resp)}) }
```

Here is the code on Django Side:

```
async def async_function(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST)
```

Basically, the `request.POST.get` and `request.POST` are empty and return `<QueryDict: {}>`. Can someone help on why it is empty?

Answer (score 0):

A genius helped me

The data is in `request.files`
Ref: [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/)